# How to correctly encode special characters in multipart/form-data POST request

Tags: php, curl, encoding

I am working on fetching the waste disposal data from our local waste disposal service, it took quite a while to understand the API (there is no official API or documentation and no one responds to a email).

The API is working now, but I am having issues with special characters with `ä, ö and ü`.

I am using `PHP` and `curl` to make the requests, requests without such characters work flawlessly.

I copied the `curl` request from Chrome and executed it in the Terminal, it worked, but I saw, that `ä` has been encoded to `\xe4`, in PHP however the `ä` gets encoded to `\u00e4` and PHP doesn't work.

If I change the `ä` directly to `\xe4` it won't work either.

Is there a specification for encoding such characters in a `multipart/form-data` `POST` request I am missing?

Comment: You probably need to make sure that the part-specific `Content-Type:` header is correct. That is the type for that specific part, not the type for the HTTP POST request itself.

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7578